# Eclipse changes deployment assembly

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, deployment, eclipse-wtp

I have a complex web application which I created via maven and deployed to tomcat using the eclipse wtp (with an external tomcat).

I had to do some changes in the deployment assembly for the project by adding some folders (due to build profiles).

Every now and then, Eclipse changes the deployment assembly and removes my adjustment. Does anyone know why and when this happens and how I can turn it off?

Using the following:

```
  Spring IDE Version: 3.6.3.201411271034-RELEASE
  Eclipse Web Developer Tools Version: 3.6.3.v201501170605
```

Comment: If you are using maven then use it for *adding some folders*.

Comment: The folders I add manually to the deployment assembly contain different files depending on the build profile. This is why I add them manually. How can I do this with maven?